# Mustache lambda function accessing its view instance 'this'

Tags: backbone.js, mustache

Is it possible for mustache lambda function to access its view instance `this`?

```
Backbone.View.extend ({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.collection = options.collection  // large backbone.collection 
    },

    parseContent: function (){
        return function (id, render){
            //this.collection is undefined below
            return this.collection.get (render (id)).get ('stuff);
        }
    }
});
```

Tried `_.bind (this.parseContent, this)` inside `initialize ()`, `this` still carry the model context  inside `parseContent ()`.

My current workaround is saving `this.collection` to my app root namespace and access from there. Wondering is there a cleaner way to do this as intended above?

Appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to pass around the function returned by `parseContent`, you should

1. bind that function before returning it with [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind),
2. and use [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) in `initialize` to force `this` in `parseContent` on each instance.

Your view could be written as

```
Backbone.View.extend ({
    initialize: function (options) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'parseContent');

        // you don't need this.collection = options.collection
        // collection is part of the special variables handled By Backbone
    },

    parseContent: function (){
        var f = function (id, render){
            console.log(this.collection);
        }

        return _.bind(f, this);
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/VNeR8/

Comment: `this.collection` inside `f` function is `undefined`.

Comment: @ChengPingOnn Could you set up a demo? Because this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/VNeR8/ works as expected.

Comment: your advice is sound.  Actually, I am using Backbone.Marionette and the context above is an `ItemView` rendering a row inside a table wraps within a `CompositeView`. Still, your solution should work, but I am still getting `undefined` inside function `f`.